# Trying to exclude a specific directory from a grep command

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, centos-6, command-line-arguments

I've got a directory that contains hundreds of sub-directories that all have dates as their names, and inside each of those sub-directories, there's a bunch of files I need to be searching through. The grep command I'm using right now is this:

`grep -ER --exclude-dir=2017060200_it2 "PATTERN" *_it2/file00*.pjson`

and the folder structure looks like this:

```
parcel/
    |--- 2015010100_it2/
        |--- file001.pjson
        |--- file002.pjson
        ...
        |--- file005.pjson
    |--- 2015010200_it2/
        |--- file001.pjson
        ...
    ...
    |--- 2017060200_it2/
        |--- file001.pjson
        |--- file002.pjson
        ...
```

I want my grep command to be searching in `file00*.pjson` for every single sub-directory EXCEPT the most recent one, in this case being `2017060200_it2`. However, my `--exclude-dir=2017060200` doesn't seem to be accomplishing this.

I'm using grep V2.20 on a CentOS 6.7 system, and when I use `grep --help`, I do get the option for using `--exclude-dir`, so I don't think this information is relevant.

Bonus: If you could show me how to get the current date and format it as `yyyyMMdd00_it2` so that I could make this a cron job, that would be awesome, but I was planning on figuring out how to do that separately once I got this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your --exclude-dir is correct, it's just that it affects the recursion - but you have explicitly specified all `*_it2` directories in the file glob, and that comes before any recursion.

I suggest using `find` instead - something like (untested)

```
find . -name 2017060200_it2 -prune -name 'file00*.pjson' -execdir grep -E "PATTERN" {} \;
```

Bonus: `date '+%Y%m%d00_it2'`

Comment: Awesome, worked really well! Had to modify the command a little bit, but this did the job! Thank you so much. Bonus: The date part worked well too, thank you!

Comment: On another note, I got this to work using `grep --exclude` instead of `grep --exlude-dir`... I'd thought `--exclude` was for files, but I guess it's just about the recursive behavior...